# Advance compare two or more csv files

Tags: python, csv, numpy, validation, bigdata

I'm just learning a Python, and as everyone knows, the best way is practice ;)
And now I have a job, and I want to try to do it in python, but I need some advice.

Well... I have a few CSV files. The structure looks like:

1st CVS
    workerID, workerName, workerPhoneNumber

2th and the other CSVs contains a subset of this first set.

I mean, in the first file there are, for example, 10,000 employees, and in each of them, there is a section of the same employees.
For example:
in the first file, I have

```
00001 Randal 555555
00002 Tom 66666
00003 Anthony 77775
00004 Mark 3424435
00005 Anna 3443223
00006 Monica 412415415
.....
```

in second file:

```
00001 Randal 555555
00004 Mark 3424435
00006 Monica 412415415
....
```

and 3th file:

```
00001 Randal 555555
00004 Mark 3424435
00005 Anna 3443223
....
```

I have to check the validity of all users in all files. I mean: check than Anna form all files have the same ID and phone in other filers and same for all results (that's huge file 100k rows). Then I will return all mismatches.
An addition problem is some "NA" in rows.

I've just finished a numpy tutorial, but i don't know how to bite it. I don't even know that a good practice to use a numpy. So I need your advice... how I can handle with this problem?

EDIT: Workes have unique names :) Its random string actually not a name :D just example :D in single file IDs is unique too

Comment: looks more like a task for [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/)

Comment: what if two employees do actually have the same name?

Comment: Are workerIDs unique or can they repeat inside single file?

Comment: Workes have uniqe names :) Its random string acctualy not a name :D just example :D in single file IDs is uniqe too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of standard functions and data structures will be enough.
Let's represents your files by a list of dictionaries using list comprehensions:

```py
header = ('id', 'name', 'phone_number')

records_1 = [{k:v for k, v in zip(header, line.strip().split(' ')} } for line in open('path_to_file1', 'r')]
records_2 = [{k:v for k, v in zip(header, line.strip().split(' ')} } for line in open('path_to_file2', 'r')]
```

Then, if you want to check your records based on the user name, use a dictionary with the name as key and the record as value:

```py
records_1 = {rec['name']: rec for rec in records_1}
records_2 = {rec['name']: rec for rec in records_2}
```

and check for each name if you have duplicated ids. If so, save it to output:

```py
seen = {}
output = []
for records, others in [(records_1, records_2), (records_2, records_1)]:
    for name, rec in records:
        if name in seen:
            continue

        if rec['id'] != others['name']['id']:
            output.append((name, rec, others['name']))
```

Note we could deduce the list of permutations using permutations from itertools:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank u for the reply! I will try ur solution!